# Index of element in random permutation for very large range

Tags: python

I am working with a *very* large range of values (0 to approx. 10^6128) and I need a way in Python to perform two-way lookups with a random permutation of the range.

Example with a smaller dataset:

```
import random

values = list(range(10))  # the actual range is too large to do this
random.shuffle(values)

def map_value(n):
    return values[n]

def unmap_value(n):
    return values.index(n)
```

I need a way to implement the `map_value` and `unmap_value` methods with values in the very large range above.

Comment: Do you need to get values from the same permutation multiple times? If so how many of the large range will you need?

Comment: do you need repetetive values on different runs

Comment: The permutation will need to be constant across multiple runs of the program (maybe using a random seed, key, etc.) and the user could potentially specify any value within the large range to either map or unmap. Also the pattern does not have to be random but should not be obvious (adjacent values shouldn't be adjacent in the mapping, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a fixed permutation of 10**6128 values is costly - memory wise.

You can create values from your range on the fly and store them in one / two dictionaries.

If you only draw comparativly few values one dict might be enough, if you have lots of values you might need 2 for faster lookup.

Essentially you

- lookup a value, if not present generate an index, store it and return it
- lookup an index, if not present, generate a value, store it and return it

Using a fixed random seed should lead to same sequences:

```
import random

class big_range():
    random.seed(42) 
    pos_value = {}
    value_pos = {}

    def map_value(self, n):
        p = big_range.value_pos.get(n)
        while p is None:
            p = random.randrange(10**6128) # works, can't use random.choice(range(10**6128))
            if p in big_range.pos_value:
                p = None
            else:
                big_range.pos_value[p]=n
                big_range.value_pos[n]=p
        return p


    def unmap_value(self, n):
        p = big_range.pos_value.get(n)
        while p is None:
            p = random.randrange(10**6128) # works, can't use random.choice(range(10**6128)) 
            if p in big_range.pos_value:
                p = None
            else:
                big_range.pos_value[n]=p
                big_range.value_pos[p]=n
        return p

br = big_range()

for i in range(10):
    print(br.map_value(i))

print(big_range.pos_value)  
print(big_range.value_pos)
```

Output:

Gibberisch humongeous number ... but it works.

You store each number twice (once as pos:number, once as number:pos) for lookup reasons. You might want to check how many numbers you can generate before your memory goes out.

You can use one dict only, but looking up the *value* to an index is not O(1) but O(n) in that case because you need to traverse `dict.items()` to find the value and return the index.

The repeatability breaks if you do other random things in between because you alter the "state" of random - you might need to do some more capsulating and maybe statekeeping inside your class using `random.getstate() / random.setstate()` to store the last state after generation of a new random as well...

If you look for most of your values it will take longer and longer to produce a "not present one" if you simple keep looping indexes from 0 to 10**6128...

---

- [random.getstate()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.getstate)
- [random.setstate()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.setstate)
- [random.randrange()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.randrange)

This is kindof fragile and more of a thought experiment - I have no clue whatfor one needs a 10**6128 range of numbers...

Comment: "10**6128 values is costly - memory wise" It's costly, number of electrons in the known universe, wise. It is unlikely that that much memory will ever exist, even if you sum all computers that have ever or will ever exist, no matter how long humanity continues making computers.

Comment: @mypet - yep - thats why its more of a thought experiment if it can be done, drawing all numbers will take its time. The number of helium atoms in the esitmated 500 billion galaxies with 400billion stars per galaxie sums up to 10**86 give or take some (https://www.universetoday.com/36302/atoms-in-the-universe/)

Comment: Let x, y, z be ints in the range. Say I run this program once and map x and the result is y. If I run the program again and map z, I will get y again. Is there any way to make the mappings consistent across runs of the program?

Comment: @okay if you tweak it - sure. you could f.e. store the things into a database and prepopulate your dicts from it before each run. Have fun.